# Python error for space in path

Tags: python, path, space, os.system

In python if I try to give path with space I'm getting error as below

```
import os  
os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\(application.exe)")
```

> '`C:\Program`' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How can I give path with space?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make it working by using `r`.

E.g. :

```
import os
cmd =r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"'
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: You don't need the `r`, just the double quotation (`'"..."'`). This passes a quoted string to the OS, which it needs to deal with the space.

Comment: in my case double quotes is not working, but this solution works.

Comment: No, I mean `'` + `"`. The outer set of `'` for Python means "send this string (including the double quotes `"`) to the shell